# Not able to execute WHERE clause in sqlite manager(Mozilla add-on)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I transfered (converted) my database to .sqlite and I'm able to open in the sqlite mozilla manager. I can also query my database  with the basic queries, for instance

```
SELECT Name, Surname FROM myTable
```

and this works perfectly.

When I try to execute a query using a WHERE statement for instance

```
SELECT Name, Surname FROM myTable WHERE Surname='roger'
```

I don't get any results, neither I get some warning message.

Note: - the database has records inside which correspond to the above where query, When I query another table it works the where clause works perfectly and gives the output. What could be the cause for such behaviour? Am I missing something?

Comment: If it works with other tables, your table is probably missing the required data. The data that looks like `'roger'` may be, for example, `'roger   '` with spaces at the end, which will not match the `=` condition. Try `WHERE Surname LIKE '%roger%'` instead, and see what you would get.

Comment: Try with `SELECT Name, Surname FROM myTable WHERE Surname like '%Roger%'"`. Probably you have some space in Surname so it doesn't match exactly.

Comment: In your first query do you find `roger` this as a result if so then check the spelling or the upper case or lower case letter.

Comment: It seems that the conversion generated extra spaces, you are right! Can you now give a solution on how to fix that, does sqlite support some trim functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
SELECT Name, Surname FROM myTable WHERE Surname like '%Roger%'
```

Probably you have some space in Surname so it doesn't match exactly.

**UPDATE:**

To trim use the built in `trim()` function of sqlite,

```
SELECT Name, Surname FROM myTable WHERE Surname = trim('Roger');
```